# chrome developer tool: how to type in the bracket [ ] characters?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My google developer tool got crazy and does not allow me to type in `[]` chars any more.

<kbd>ALTGR</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd> now moves me backward in my tool navigation history instead of the `[` char

<kbd>ALTGR</kbd> + <kbd>)</kbd> now moves me forward in my tool navigation history instead of the `]` char

Comment: See https://crbug.com/685674 presumably fixed in v59 so you can develop in Chrome canary or switch your keyboard layout to US default (or add it in the system keyboard settings).

Comment: The fix was just approved for v57 so expect an autoupdate soon.

Comment: Had same problem, I've updated and it's working now